# Server didn't send any data? Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a hosting where I have put up a server.js file that listens to the 8080 port. When I go to the site on my browser, it just loads for a few minutes and drops an error message saying it didn't send any data.

I did remember to append :8080 at the end of the domain name.

Comment: Have you tried running the server locally on your own computer? Does that work? Also, it's close to impossible to tell what the problem as the question is currently written, because it contains no specific information about your problem (e.g., a short code that reproduces your problem).

Comment: Please add more information, are you using express or simple http module? hosting is aws, heroku? Linux, windows ? are you using docker?